# Getting only certain values from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with the following values

```
    array (size=7)
  0 => string '020120140759' (length=12)
  1 => string '020120140759' (length=12)
  2 => string '020120140759' (length=12)
  3 => string '020220140759' (length=12)
  4 => string '020220140759' (length=12)
  5 => string '020320140759' (length=12)
  6 => string '020320140759' (length=12)
```

You will notice that the value of certain numbers are the same, I want to extract the last value of each kind that occurs in the array so that a new array will look something likes this.

```
array (size=2)

  2 (this will change to 0 ) => string '020120140759' (length=12)
  6 (this will change to 1 ) => string '020320140759' (length=12)
```

I have tried quite a couple of things but i haven't been successful . Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_unique](http://php.net/array_unique) is the way to go.

```
var_dump( array_unique( array_reverse($yourOriginalArrayHere) ) );
```

Comment: Is there a way to take in the last instead of the first. It is crtical that  i take in the last of each kind.

Comment: Technically, you should be able to reverse it first, then take out the unique elements, I'll update my answer.

Comment: array_reverse() function is for you!

Comment: @Michael Is there a way to get the original index numbers of these values ?

Comment: Since you need more and more custom features not from the original question, it might be a good idea to simply iterate over the original array and take all you need from it with the necessary modifications.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array array_unique ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )`

the Sorting flags will be

```
SORT_REGULAR
SORT_NUMERIC
SORT_STRING
SORT_LOCALE_STRING
```

example

```
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

//first step : Exchanges all keys with their associated values in an array $newArray
//second step: get $newArray's key
[array_flip][1]
[array_keys][2]

$array = array(
  0 =>  '020120140759' ,
  1 =>  '020120140759' ,
  2 =>  '020120140759' ,
  3 =>  '020220140759' ,
  4 =>  '020220140759' ,
  5 =>  '020320140759' ,
  6 =>  '020320140759' 
 );

$newArray = array_keys( array_flip($array) );
echo '<pre>';  
var_dump($newArray);
echo '</pre>';
```